# Need a SUMIF formula to use criteria from 2 columns in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement

I'm using Excel 2010 and I need a formula which can take criteria from 2 different columns, SUM the result of all matching rows:

The columns are Area Manager and Project Type and if both criteri amatch I'd like to SUM the results from a third column on all matching rows.

e.g =SUMIF(F:F,"Adam Jones",H:H ) and =SUMIF(G:G,"Special Projects",H:H )
but all in one cell?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b)

`SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2], ...)`

`=SUMIFS(H:H,F:F,"=Adam Jones",G:G,"=Special Projects")`